# Why Forward Image Warping leave holes in the image?

Tags: computer-vision

I am warping first image using Homography and the new image consist of holes. What is the reason for that ?

Comment: It is going to be really difficult to help you/or say anything meaningful without more details. What exactly are you doing? How are you interpolating? Can you show a couple of images?

Comment: I get it. Actually, it happens because when we use Homography matrix to get new image coordinates, they don't come out to be exact pixel values but some floating point values, which are rounded off. Now, many pixel values don't get any value assigned to them. Hence, we get holes in the new image.

Answer (score 0):

Homography is a transformation matrix to map image pixel coordinate (ref [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision))). Thus, assume the homogenous coordinate of the image's top-left corner is: `p0 = [0 0 1]^T`. Under some general homography `H`, it is probably that `p = H * p0` is not the top-left corner of the new warped image so that there will be holes in the top-left corner of the new image. A more intuitive example is shown below (espeically for similarity transformation, the image size will shrink):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shape of the holes.

If by *hole* you mean black areas (most presumably with triangular or trapezoidal shape), then it's an artifact coming from the fact that a homography maps a rectangle to a trapeze (see also [rookiepig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047328/rookiepig)'s answer, especially the drawing inside).

If the *holes* are really holes spread all over your output image, then it means that something bad has happened (bug somewhere, or your homography may be degenerate because of a poor estimation process).

You can try to compare the result of the direct call to the homography warping to the output of the `cv::remap()` function, with the mappings obtained from the homography matrix:

```
/* Assuming the input image is not empty */
cv::Mat originalImage; // Not empty!

/* Our outputs */
cv::Mat homographyOutput, remapOutput;

cv::Mat H;             // This is our homography
cv::Mat map_x, map_y;  // These matrices are needed for cv::remap()

/* Compute mappings from homography */
map_x.create(originalImage.size(), CV_32FC1);
map_y.create(originalImage.size(), CV_32FC1);
for (int y = 0; y < originalImage.size().height; ++y)
  for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.size().width; ++x)
  {
    double x_mapped = H.at<double>(0,0)*x + H.at<double>(0,1)*y + 
                        H.at<double>(0,2);
    double y_mapped = H.at<double>(1,0)*x + H.at<double>(1,1)*y + 
                        H.at<double>(1,2);
    double w = H.at<double>(2,0)*x + H.at<double>(2,1)*y + 
                        H.at<double>(2,2);
    x_mapped /= w;
    y_mapped /= w;
    map_x.at<float>(y,x) = (float)x_mapped;
    map_y.at<float>(y,x) = (float)y_mapped;
  }

/* Now call remap */
cv::remap(originalImage, remapOutput, map_x, map_y);
```

I leave it to you for the homography mapping part (using `cv::warpPerspective()`). Both results should be similar (if not equal, dpeending on your interpolation and border settings). You can also add additional sanity checks in the mapping computation loop to understand what's wrong.